# Can RichTextLabels be prevented from antialiasing certain characters?

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm working on a game with a pixel art style font, and I'd like to be able to use RichTextLabels for displaying it, but certain characters (like "[", "]", "{", "}", "#", "@", etc.) are antialiased in RichTextLabels (and possibly rendered in a different font?) despite being present in the pixel perfect font I created and working fine with normal Labels.

[image of antialiased labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlBxX.png)

Is there any way to fix this?

I've tried using [lb] and [rb] instead of the "[" and "]" characters in RichTextLabels, enabling and disabling bbcode, and messing with whether subpixels are allowed in the rendering settings of the project, but nothing seems to change this. The problem persists in both the editor and in the game when running.

Comment: This seems to be a long standing problem... This is what comes to mind: You can try enabling `multichannel_signed_distance_field` on the font import, alternatively a large oversampling, although I don't think that helps in this case.

Comment: @Theraot yeah none of the font import settings seem to fix this :/ i always love when an issue i'm having is a "long standing problem" that's my favorite,,, thank you for your help tho!!

Comment: This is what I mean: signed distance field fonts were blurry in Godot 2! The feature was dropped for Godot 3, and re-added for Godot 3.2, a fix was in work but never finished. Instead Godot 4 got multichannel signed distance field, which are supposed to fix this, but apparently not in rich text labels? I'd to go ahead and open an issue: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues (After all the old issues were Godot 3, and this is considered fixed in Godot 4, so I don't think anybody is looking at this).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. I'd set the font for RichTextLabels inside the theme, as well as a default font for the entire theme, but the version of the font file I set for the RichTextLabel override was an older version which was missing some characters.

Clearing and resetting the font override fixed the issue.